# Shall I version the .vagrant folder

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

We have a vagrant project where we manage our production machines, what will be the best way for us to share the their status?

For now I've shared the .vagrant folder via the git repo? Is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 22):

Do not include the `.vagrant` folder into version control as that includes specifics to the actual initialize VM which is different on each initialized instance and not intended to be included in version control. The best thing to include is the `Vagrantfile` and any configuration management scripts which provision the VM.

Comment: Yap, but in this case my colleagues don't see the status of the machines and can't control them

Comment: Could you elaborate on your environment and intent?

Comment: I have a bunch of boxes running the production env and I will like anyone on my team being able to up/down them, this means that they should know their status to begin with

Comment: I wish there was more documentation about the intent. I was thinking of moving by `bootstrap.sh` file *into* the `.vagrant` folder, because why not? But I trust you. Still, it seems to be that the actual project files should not be under the same repo as the Vagratfile.